# jquery code with curly braces in selecting jquery object

Tags: jquery

After searching for a semi circle fill solution i came across this codepen code.
What does selector `{p:0}` select? Also how var `perc` value got into `{p:perc}`?

https://codepen.io/jagathish/pen/ZXzbzN

```js
$(".progress").each(function(){

  var $bar = $(this).find(".bar");
  var $val = $(this).find("span");
  var perc = parseInt( $val.text(), 10);

  $({p:0}).animate({p:perc}, {
    duration: 3000,
    easing: "swing",
    step: function(p) {
      $bar.css({
        transform: "rotate("+ (45+(p*1.8)) +"deg)", // 100%=180° so: ° = % * 1.8
        // 45 is to add the needed rotation to have the green borders at the bottom
      });
      $val.text(p|0);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does selector `{p:0}` select?

`{p:0}` is an object; it doesn't select anything. This object is then wrapped in a jQuery object and you can then use jQuery methods to amend the properties of the original object. In this case they are using `animate()` to increment the value of `p` (which starts at `0`) at intervals to update the progress bars in the UI.

> How does the perc value got into `{p:perc}`

The `perc` value is defined within the `each()` block. It relates to the `text()` of the `span` within each `.progress` element.

Comment: What's the difference in using $(this).animate(...) ?

Comment: That would entirely depend on what `this` is a reference to

Comment: Yes, more in the example of the question? https://jsfiddle.net/k8p64nrx/

Answer (score -1):

As per [jQuery doc](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-object):

> Working With Plain Objects At present, the only operations supported
>   on plain JavaScript objects wrapped in jQuery are:
>   .data(),.prop(),.on(), .off(), .trigger() and .triggerHandler(). The
>   use of .data() (or any method requiring .data()) on a plain object
>   will result in a new property on the object called
>   jQuery{randomNumber} (eg. jQuery123456789).

So, answering your first question: `$({p:0})` select nothing

Second one was answered pretty good above and I can't add anything new or other explantation.